# Unable to login to Office 365 with AD FS alternative login

Tags: active-directory, office365, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I configured a AD FS 3.0 server an proxy and federated this with Office 365.
The active directory domain name is domain.local, the users email address is domain-plus.be. It's not an option to change the users UPN so I chose to configure [the alternative login ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configuring-alternate-login-id) for Office 365. I also changed the Microsoft Office 365 Identity Platform claim following [this post](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/04/office-365-configuring-ad-fs-dirsync-with-an-alternate-login/).
That way users would be able to login to adfs with there email address user@domain-plus.be without changing the upn.

Now i'm experiencing the following situation:

- When I login to a **domain joined computer** and add the AD FS signin page URL in the internet sites of the user. The user navigates to https://portal.office.com, enters his emails address and is redirected and automatically logged on to the Office 365 portal. No password is requested, as it should be.
- When I use the same **domain joined computer** and use Chrome instead of IE, i'm redirected to the AD FS signin page after entering the email address on https://portal.office.com. But when I enter the password in there I get the following error in the AD FS logs:

***Protocol Name:*** 
wsfed 
**Relying Party:** 
urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline 
**Exception details:** 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details. ---> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.AccountPolicy.ADAccountLookupException: MSIS8013: CanonicalName:'' of the user:'CN=Testmailmigration,OU=Users,OU=Bio,DC=BIO,DC=local' is in bad format. 
The user is still the same user that was logged on to the Office 365 portal minutes ago. There users are working internally so the AD FS proxy is not used.

- When I try to login external I experience the same issues as the 2nd
  scenario.

The username and password are correct, that we can conclude from scenario 1.
Does someone also experienced this error when configuring a simular setup?

Thanks in advance,
Gijs.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve the issue with Chrome by expanding the SupportedUserAgents on ADFS with the following command:

> Set-AdfsProperties –WIASupportedUserAgents @("MSAuthHost/1.0/In-Domain","MSIE 6.0","MSIE 7.0","MSIE 8.0","MSIE 9.0","MSIE 10.0","Trident/7.0", "MSIPC","Windows Rights Management Client","Mozilla/5.0","Edge/12")

Regarding the authentication issues, we noticed that there were special read permissions on the OU were the users existed. These permissions were changed on purpose or because of a software installation (like a cpsm portal).

Authenticated users were not able to do a full read on the OU anymore, so a LDAP query wasn't possible.
We gave our service accounts full read rights on the necessary OU's which solved the issue.

So in our case the following error wasn't about receiving data in bad format, we couldn't read the data at all.

> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.AccountPolicy.ADAccountLookupException: MSIS8013: CanonicalName:'' of the user:'CN=Testmailmigration,OU=Users,OU=Bio,DC=BIO,DC=local' is in bad format

Regards,
Gijs